# Hydbrid App In IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I Already done updating the password in database using `SQLAdpaters` in IBM `Worklight` Hybrid App. 
I am Working on Hybrid App using IBM `Worklight`. I am updating user password in database using `SQLAdapter`, but I want to store password in encrypted format. I already have the encryption and decryption logic in java class. How can I integrate that java class with my hybrid app?

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE USERS SET USERPASSWORD=? WHERE USERNAME = ? AND USERPASSWORD=? ");

function updateUserPassword(newPassword,userName,password) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [newPassword,userName,password]
    });
}
```

Comment: The most common alternative is to 1) Encrypt the password with a one-way encryption algorithm before you store it in the database, 2) program your hybrid app to use the same algorithm on the password the user enters, 3) do a simple text compare of the encrypted password read from the database and the encrypted password the user entered: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/md5_encrypt_passwords.php

Comment: I already have encryption and decreption logic in My Java Class.. When iam storing the password using My Hybrid app i want to convert password using the java class and store it into database and also retreving user information i have to decrept password using java class and display to user using hybrid app

Comment: issue has been solved.

Comment: @LingaReddy, please write the answer to the issue; don't keep the question unanswered.

Comment: changed code as follows var userpwdUpdateStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE USERS SET USERPASSWORD=? WHERE USERNAME = ? AND USERPASSWORD=? ");
function updateUserPassword(newPassword,userName,password) {
 var encryptdecryptutility = new com.til.mobileerp.core.utility.SysCRAESencrpDecrp();
 var encryptnewPassword = encryptdecryptutility.encrypt(newPassword);
 var encryptoldPassword = encryptdecryptutility.encrypt(password);
 return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
  preparedStatement : userpwdUpdateStatement,
  parameters : [encryptnewPassword,userName,encryptoldPassword]
 });
}

Comment: @LingaReddy, please write it as the ANSWER to the question - not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed code as follows

```
var userpwdUpdateStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE USERS SET USERPASSWORD=? WHERE USERNAME = ? AND USERPASSWORD=? "); 

function updateUserPassword(newPassword,userName,password) { 
  var encryptdecryptutility = new com.abcd.bgf.SysCRAESencrpDecrp(); 
  var encryptnewPassword = encryptdecryptutility.encrypt(newPassword); 
  var encryptoldPassword = encryptdecryptutility.encrypt(password); 

  return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({ 
      preparedStatement : userpwdUpdateStatement, 
      parameters : [encryptnewPassword,userName,encryptoldPassword] 
  });
}
```